# Insertar una Lista<Class> en un Map<String, dynamic> en dart

Tags: arraylist, flutter, map, dart

El problema que tengo una Lista de datos de la siguiente clase

```
class ingreso_Egreso_Dummy{
  int tipo;
  String monto;
  String moneda;
  String descripcion;
}
```

Entonces el problema es quiero ingresar esos datos en un Map que luego se va a formatear en json, y que estoy construyendo en texto plano 
de la siguiente manera

```
    Map<String, dynamic> body;
        body = {
          "Cod_Prom": "01",
          "CodCli": "003526",
          "Status": _index_status.toString(),
          "NOMBRE": controller_nombre.text,
          "APELLIDOS": controller_apellidos.text,
          "solicitud":[{
            "Cod_Solicit": 1.toString(),
            "Fecha": DateFormat("y-d-M").format(DateTime.now()),
            "Status_Solicit": "E",}],
          "prestamo":[{
            "Monto_Solicit":controller_monto_solic.text,
            "Plazo":controller_plazo.text,
            "Cod_TipoPlazo":_index_tipoplazo.toString(),
            "Nombre_Resp":controller_nombreresp.text,
            "Telf_Resp":controller_telefonoresp.text,}],
          "Ingresos": [{
    //// Aqui quiero crear una iteracion de la lista que me devuelva
   //// un mapa por cada valor de la lista, en plan

   //// "Descripcion": Listaingresos[i].descripcion;

   //// o algo asi
            })
          }]
        };
```

Cualquier ayuda es apreciada, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta lo que mencionas lo ideal seria crear una función ( `toMap()` ) que nos permita transformar nuestro Objeto tipo `ingreso_Egreso_Dummy` a Map.

```
   class Ingreso_Egreso_Dummy {
  final int tipo;
  final String monto;
  final String moneda;
  final String descripcion;

  Ingreso_Egreso_Dummy(this.tipo, this.monto, this.moneda, this.descripcion);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['tipo'] = this.tipo;
    data['monto'] = this.monto;
    data['moneda'] = this.moneda;
    data['description'] = this.descripcion;
    return data;
  }
}

void main() {

Map<String, dynamic> body;
  final List listaIngresos = [
    Ingreso_Egreso_Dummy(1, '123', 'peso', 'sueldo'),
    Ingreso_Egreso_Dummy(2, '456', 'peso', 'bono'),
    Ingreso_Egreso_Dummy(3, '789', 'peso', 'regalo')
  ];

  body = {
    "Ingresos": []
  };

  //Iterar entre la lista de ingresos y agregarlos a nuestro Map body
  var listMap = listaIngresos.map((ingreso) => ingreso.toMap());
  body['Ingresos'].addAll(listMap);

  print('${body['Ingresos']}');
```

**Algunos consejos:**

1. Las clases se suelen nombran utilizando CamelCase.
2. Intenta dentro de lo posible de ser concistente en la menera como nombras los
   KEY(Maps).

Comment: con respecto a lo que mencionas encontre una manera un tanto extraña pero funcional de sacar los datos de la lista sin un loop, `ingresos.map((ingreso)=> ingreso.toJson()).toList()`,  pero tu respuesta tambien funciona asi que la voy a marcar solo te voy a pedir que lo metas dentro de `"Ingresos": [{
          }]` para que tenga la forma que almenos en mi caso ando buscando.... y con respecto a tus recomendaciones, las entiendo pero estoy montando la app sobre una base de datos ya montada, y estoy tratando de mantener el formato de ella

Comment: Muy buena observación, gracias. Ahora entiendo lo del camelCase. Espero que la modificación se ajuste mas a los que andas buscando.